# IBM Watson Assistant V1 - conversation in loop

Tags: asp.net-core, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I have created a web api project in asp.net core using IBM SDK assistantV1 to comunicate with my IBM chatbot. But I can't keep a dialog with my bot - after three question the conversation starts over.

I am sending context and message to my api. The code below is my service:

```
 public MessageResponse CallAssistant(MessagemRequisicao MessagemRequisicao)
        {
            MessageRequest messageRequest = new MessageRequest()
            {
                Input = new MessageInput()
                {
                    Text = MessagemRequisicao.mensagem                    
                },
                Context = MessagemRequisicao.contexto
            };

            var result = _assistant.Message(_assistantId, messageRequest);


            if (result != null)
            {
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                var t = _assistant.GetWorkspace(_assistantId);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

And this is my Controller:

[HttpPost]

```
public MessageResponse Post([FromBody] MessagemRequisicao MessagemRequisicao)
{
    return assist.CallAssistant(MessagemRequisicao);
}
```

And this code is my angular app:

```
sendMessage() {
        let mes = this.mensagem;
        this.mensagem = '';
        this.insertElement(this.voce(mes));

        this.service.Post('values', { mensagem: mes, contexto: this.contexto }).subscribe(result => {
            this.contexto = result.context;
            result ? this.insertElement(this.robo(result.output.text)) : null;
        });
    }
```

My entity:

```
public class MessagemRequisicao
{
    public string mensagem { get; set; }
    public Context contexto { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Check to see if the issue happens in the Try it out window of Watson Assistant. If it does, it's an issue with your dialog. If it doesn't its related to your context object in your code not being maintained.

Comment: I tryed this and work normal, but my dialog when realized in my asp.net core app it crashes.